# Dynamically create div and into a static div

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click of button I am trying to create one div and try to append static div into that and this is giving error.

> Uncaught TypeError: elm.appendChild is not a function.

```
function s()
{
    var elm = '<div' +
        'style="background-color:orange;height:125px;width:75px;"'+
        '</div>';           
    var x=document.getElementById("staticDiv")          
    elm.appendChild(x);         
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="staticDiv">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color:grey;">
            <div>"Mumbai"
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>    
<input type="button" value="ss" onclick="s()"/>
```

I want to append static div into new div which is created dynamically.

Comment: There's no jQuery here at all. Is this what you meant?

Comment: elm  is not an element, it's a string. You need to use document.createElement

Comment: I want to append static div into new div which is creating dynamcially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code have many issues. Try like this:

```
var elm = document.createElement('div');
elm.className = 'some_demo_class';   // add all your css styles in a class
var x = document.getElementById("staticDiv");
x.appendChild(elm);
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `document.getElementById("staticDiv")` instead of `document.getElementById("ss")`?

Comment: yes, I want to create dynamic div  and add static div into that

Answer (score 0):

`elm` is a string, not an actual `HTMLElement`. What you're looking for is more like:

```
var elm = document.createElement('div');
elm.style.height = '125px';
elm.style.width = '125px';
elm.style['background-color'] = 'orange';
```

The `HtmlElement` object contains `appendChild`, but `String` does not.